# How to choose correct Service Fabric Reliability Tier?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, azure-vm-scale-set

I'm reading [the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity) on Service Fabric cluster capacity, reliability tiers, and durability tiers. The article (at this time of writing) lists the following tiers:

- Platinum - Run the System services with a target replica set count of 9
- Gold - Run the System services with a target replica set count of 7
- Silver - Run the System services with a target replica set count of 5
- Bronze - Run the System services with a target replica set count of 3

Is there any **disadvantage** / **performance implications** to using a high reliability tier (like Platinum)? I'm creating several clusters that will span at least 50-100VMs with a combination of stateless and stateful services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. Yes, technically the replication of changes to the system services will take longer, however in practice this has not made a significant difference in the performance of the system services. The replicas are almost always in a set of ~5 physical racks, the data is stored on local disks, so the performance tradeoff is (usually) more than worth the safety gained. YMMV of course.